# Can I apply a transformation to each element in an IQueryable and get the result as an IQueryable?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, iqueryable

In my C# application, I have a method that returns IQueryable where MyClass is a class for Entity Framework code-first.  It looks like this.

```
// Is a class for Entity Framework code-first
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int LuckyNumber {get; set;}
}

public IQueryable<MyClass> GetQuery()
{
    var query = doSomethingToGetQuery();
    return query;
}
```

Suppose I want to create a method that returns an IQueryable, but I want my query to apply some transformation to the data before returning it.

If I had a method that was returning IEnumerable, I could write something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<MyClass> GetEnumerable()
{
    var query = doSomethingToGetQuery();
    return query.Select(x =>
    {
        var y = x;
        y.LuckyNumber = 2 * x.LuckyNumber;
        return y;
    }
}
```

Thus, I would have an IEnumerable that would return the same data is the original function, but it would double the LuckyNumber.

Suppose I want to do something similar, but I want to return an IQueryable where the result would be the same as querying the original query, but in the result, the LuckyNumber value is doubled, or some other transformation is applied.

Also, I don't want to execute a SQL query that returns the whole dataset, especially if I'm retrieving a single record by ID.

Can I do this in C#?

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose I want to create a method that returns an IQueryable, but I want my query to apply some transformation to the data before returning it.

Sure.  You just need to call [Queryable.Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.select?view=netframework-4.7.2), instead of [Enumerable.Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.7.2).  If you pass a `Func<TSource,TResult>` then it will resolve to a call to Enumerable.Select and your query will be executed before the additional expressions are applied.

However if you pass an `Expression<Func<TSource,TResult>>` then the overload will resolve to Queryable.Select and your query will be modified, with the new projection wrapping the existing query.

The easiest way to get this right is with LINQ.  EG:

```
public IQueryable<MyClass> GetEnumerable()
{
    IQueryable<MyClass> query = null; //whatever

    IQueryable<MyClass> q2 = 
             from m in query
             select new MyClass()
             {
                 LuckNumber = m.LuckNumber * 2
             };
    return q2;      
 }
```

Note that if you do this, you will probably defeat the ability of an ORM to write an efficient query that pushed predicates through the projection to the base tables.

Comment: You are correct to guess that EF won't play ball with this, unfortunately.

Comment: SQL views have the same issue.

Comment: I've had to put this aside to work on another issue for now, but I have an idea about how I might do this.  Perhaps I can create class that implements IQueryable.  The new class can execute the query on the old IQueryable and then apply the transformation to the result before returning it to calling code.  This would give me the advantage that I can pass an instance of the new class to anything that expects IQueryable as an argument.